# monitor rest call on my eclipse using the tcp/ip monitor

Tags: java, eclipse, rest

I will be happy if someone can help me to understand:

I have a spring  application ruining on tomcat. From this application I'm doing rest calls (using restTemplate) to a remote application (lets say : http://connect2.myremoteApp.com).

I would like to monitor this call on my eclipse using the tcp/ip monitor.
I am trying to understand how to configure this :

Local monitoring port : ???? - this I don't understand - what port to set ?

- Host name : I guess  http://connect2.myremoteApp.com
- Port : I guess
  80 or 8080 depends on remote webserver configration
- Type : I guess
  HTTP

Please advice

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You would set your local monitoring port to whatever you like that's available.
I use 8081

Local monitoring port: 8081
Hostname: connect2.myremoteApp.com
Port: 80  (Probably 80 since you're trying to get an http website)

Then in your application have it try to connect to localhost:8081 instead of connect2.myremoteApp.com that should forward it to the correct location and log it.